# why doesn't line.split('\s') do the same as line.split()?

Tags: python, split

I have a very very simple program that parses a csv file that has rows of text records whose columns are separated by a single tab character.

I understand split() by default splits on whitespace so explicitly specifying a whitespace pattern isn't needed, but my question is why won't an explicitly specified pattern for whitespace work?  Or is '\s' or r'\s' not the right pattern/regex?  I searched on stackoverflow and found mentioning of string split() being an older method, which I don't really understand since I am very new to python.  Does string split() not support regex?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in f:
    field = line.split()
    field2 = line.split('\s')
    print field[1], field2[1]
f.close
```

I tried doing line.split(r'\s') and that doesn't work either, but line.split('\t') works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `\t` really represents a tab character in a string (like `\n` is the new line character, see here a [list of valid escape sequences](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)), but `\s` is a special **regular expression character class** for white spaces.

[`str.split`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) does not accept regular expressions. If you want to split with regular expressions, you have to use [`re.split`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split).

Demonstration:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "This\sis a weird\sstring"
>>> str.split("\s")                    # treated literally
['This', 'is a weird', 'string'] 
>>> re.split("\s", str)                # regex
['This\\sis', 'a', 'weird\\sstring']
```

Comment: Felix, so the string split is different from the regex split?  I am new to python, hence the confusion.

Comment: @software engineer: Yes, the normal `split` treats the characters literally. As `\s` is not special character (like `\t` is), it will try to split your string at literally at `\s`.

Comment: Yes, re.split and str.split are different. Documentation of both can be found here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html, http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 1):

`string.split()` takes a string as it's argument, and splits based on that string. That's all. `\t` is a, ASCII tab character, while `\s` is simply `\`+`s` in this case.

For a regex split, you want to import `re` and use `re.split()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `string.split()` function does not take a regular expression parameter. Try [`re.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"\s+", "a  b")
['a', 'b']
```